# Rendering the dropdown part of a SelectField without an invisible overlay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Popup-like components in Material-UI render on an invisible top overlay that is programmatically appended directly to `body`. For example, when a [SelectField](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) or [DropDownMenu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu) is opened:

```
<body>
    <div id="app-container>
        <div ...>
            <!-- This is where the SelectField is rendered. -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ...>
        <!-- This div is: -->
        <!-- (1) where the visible dropdown is rendered when open -->
        <!-- (2) a full-screen overlay -->
        <!-- (3) removed when the dropdown is closed -->
    </div>
</body>
```

This mechanism is in place so that (1) the user can "click away" to close the open dropdown, (2) the user does not accidentally click on another control when attempting to close the open dropdown.

However, **I need to allow clickaways to actually hit the underlying element**, without being blocked by the overlay. This can be accomplished in the [Popover](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/popover) component by using the `useLayerForClickAway` prop:

```
<Popover useLayerForClickAway={false} ... >
    ...
</Popover>
```

Unfortunately, **no such option exists for [SelectField](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) or [DropDownMenu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu)** (or seems to exist, it's not documented), and I need one of these instead of a Popover.

Moreover, I don't seem to find any option that allows to reliably identify the overlay element created by the dropdown, beside getting the last element in `body` immediately after the dropdown opened (which is hackish at best). Material-UI also doesn't seem to offer a way to manually override the inline styles of this overlay element.

**So, what's the "appropriate" way to disable the invisible overlay, and allow clicks when the dropdown is open?**

Comment: Any work-around?